# SAP UI5 rendering built-in buttons

Tags: sapui5

I use Full Stack Web IDE and I use SAP UI 1.52 version. I have migrated my code from 1.38 to 1.52. When I run my Web application on Fiori Lanchpad I get wizard buttons like this:
[image]

But if I run it in IDE in preview mode it looks properly: 
  [image]
Also other controls. It doesn't matter which theme I use.
So I think the problem is in our Fiori Lanchpad settings. 
I explored all settings that I can change, nothing helps.

Is the anybody here who knows or who can give me direction?

Comment: What are the system details of the system where you have the Launchpad?

Comment: SAP-Internal (Canary)
SAPUI5 Version: Maintenance 1.52
Access type: External

Comment: when the buttons are rendered wrongly, press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+P key combination to check the real version you are loading. Is it the 1.52 ?? or still 1.38 ?? Also, go the the browser tools, and check one of your application files, to see if they have the last changes you did. Maybe you are loading cached libraries or app files, and they are not the newest.

Comment: Thanks, I did it. The version is 1.52. On technical Information Dialog (after Ctrl+Alt+Shift+P key combination) buttons are rendered wrongly too.

Comment: This looks very strange.

- Did you check your Browser Zoom?
- Did you check your Font size (e.g. 150% on a HiDef-Display)
- Did you check, if this error happens with different Browsers? 
- Do your colleague encounters the same error? 
- Did you try to change the UI5 Version in the technical Information dialog (Ctrl+Shift+ALt+S)?

Comment: Does the Launchpad have a custom theme? Try running `sap.ui.getCore().applyTheme("sap_belize")` in the console when the app is loaded in the Launchpad. This will force the app to reload with the standard Belize theme. If that fixes it, you will need to look at the custom theme for your launchpad.